# Media Queries Problems With Bigger Phone Screens

Tags: html, css, dom, media-queries

I seem to be having issues with my styling, when I check my styling on my Samsung galaxy S4 it seems to apply the same styles as on my desktop.

Is this because the S4's resolution is very high?

I can't seem to get around it, as the handheld query doesn't seem to apply itself to it.

CSS Code:

```
@media screen {
    //Desktop Screens
    * { 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        border: 0; 
    }
    .clear { 
        clear:both; 
    } 

    .right { 
        float: right; 
    } 

    .left { 
        float: left; 
    }
    p.title {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    body 
    {
        font: 80% / 1 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; 
        background: #877781; 
        color: #0c0c0c;
        text-align: center;
    } 
    .login_cont {
        height: 80%;
        width: 15%;
        font: 80% / 1 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
        min-height: 200px;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #dadada;
        border: 1px solid #0c0c0c;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #0c0c0c;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .login_cont label{
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font: 150% / 1 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .login_cont h1 {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font: 250% / 1 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .login_cont input {
        height: 20px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 10px
    }
    .login_cont input[type='submit'] {
        height: 20px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    //Traditional phones
    .login_cont {
        height: 70%;
        width: 80%; 
    }
    .login_cont input {
        height: 20px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: 10px
    }
    .login_cont input[type='submit'] {
        height: 20px;
        width: 1px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0) and (max-width: 1080px) {
    //Bigger phones
    .login_cont {
        height: 70%;
        width: 80%; 
    }
    .login_cont input {
        height: 20px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 10px
    }
    .login_cont input[type='submit'] {
        height: 50px;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

Would it be better to use the media queries to include different stylesheets or is this way just as good?

Answer (score 0):

media queries check on screenwidth in pixels.
so, if the desktop layout fits, it fits. easy as that.
What's the problem? Looking different on different cellphones? That's no problem.
Creating layouts for your site, does not mean it must always look exactly the same, it means it must be looking good as possible in all cases:)
[edit]
Resolution of S4: Size  1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density)
So you have to adjust your media screenwidth properties. But that certainly becomes a problem with a horizontal view of 1920....
else you give desktop viewers (how many are there nowadays) a cellphone view too?

So i think you dont solve it with the mediaqueries alone. I know that there exists a PHP-class for recognizing cellphones. maybe someone else has a better solution.

[/edit]

[2nd edit]
with this php script you could recognize all mobile devices: http://mobiledetect.net/
[/2nd edit]

Comment: The problem is that I need the divs to expand on mobile devices and the text to be larger. I want a different set of styles for mobile devices.

Comment: I added a link to my answer for checking mobile devices server side with php

Comment: Sadly this app isn't in PHP so that script isn't much use, I was just wondering if CSS was finally able to solve the long fight between different screen sizes, but it doesn't quite seem to be full proof yet sadly.